# How to hide window

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have two jframe windows and I want to hide the NewJFrameSplash window after a while but I am having trouble succeeding with **setVisible(true)**
What can I be doing wrong?

as the code shows I start the NewJFrameSplash window and at the end of a while start the NewJFrame and hide the NewJFrameSplash.

```
static NewJFrameSplash frame;
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrameSplash().setVisible(true);             
        }
    });

 try {
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
 frame = new NewJFrameSplash();
 frame.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Thread.sleep(5000);`, use a Swing `Timer` instead. `new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);` is just going to make a new window and make it visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Thread.sleep(5000);`, you run the risk of blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, or, if you're using a second thread, violating the single threaded nature of the API.

Instead, use a Swing `Timer` instead.

`new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);` is just going to make a new window and make it visible, twice.  You need to use `setVisible(false)` on the instance of the window you've created earlier.

As a basic example...

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        NewJFrameSplash frame = new NewJFrameSplash();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                // Create next window
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }
});
```

Take a look at [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Swing also provides "splash screen" support.  You should take a closer look at [How to create a splash screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) for more details